# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I was following the [machine learning tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_LwzRVP7bg) and using [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/HTRU2). However while the person in the video had no problem runnning the code, I received an error that the numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'columns'

below is the code I ran

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
```

```
cols = ['integrated_mean','integrated_standard_deviation','integrated_excess_kurtosis','integrated_skewness','DM_mean','DM_standard_deviation','DM_excess_kurtosis','DM_skewness','class']
df = pd.read_csv("HTRU_2.data", names = cols)
```

```
train, valid, test = np.split(df.sample(frac = 1), [int(0.6*len(df)), int(0.8*len(df))])
```

```
def scale_dataset(dataframe, oversample = False):
    X = dataframe[dataframe.columns[:-1]].values
    y = dataframe[dataframe.columns[-1]].values

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

    if oversample:
        ros = RandomOverSampler()
        X, y = ros.fit_resample(X, y)

    data = np.hstack((X, np.reshape(y, (-1, 1))))

    return data, X, y
```

```
train, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = True)
valid, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = False)
test, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = False)
```

I do not know what is happening and how to fix it, I've tried searching elsewhere but I have no idea. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you understand the difference between a pandas dataframe and a numpy array?

Comment: Honestly, no. I was just following that tutorial. Sorry

Comment: @TheBorgQueen please do not write "solved" in the question title. You can accept an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find the minute in the tutorial, but may be it's just a consequence of copy-paste.

In the function `scale_dataset` you make `data` a numpy array and then you assign that value to `train` variable. But when you come again with `scale_dataset` for `valid` data set you want to use this `train' data set as a pandas dataframe but in that moment it's a numpy array.

My common sense tells me you want to use `valid` data set instead of `train` and so on like this:

```
train, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = True)
valid, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(valid, oversample = False)
test, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(test, oversample = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same video and got the same result. I found at the end it's because she is using the same variable name.

```
train, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = True)
```

Initially, the train variable is a dataframe but after running the function scale_dataset, it becomes a numpy array. Hence, when you call the function again, it errors out with 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'

To fix, I just changed the variable name so the dataframe train will still be the same.

```
d_train, X_train, y_train = scale_dataset(train, oversample = True)
```

Comment: Nice. By the way, you are welcome to indent code lines by four spaces, with an empty line above and below, to make it stand out as code

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
X = dataframe[dataframe.columns[:-1]].values
y = dataframe[dataframe.columns[-1]].values
```

I did

```
X = dataframe[:, :-1]
y = dataframe[:, -1]
```

And now all the codes work fine now

Comment: Note, that ChatGPT generated answers are currently **banned** on stackoverflow. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned This answer is technically correct so I edited it to just be it, but do not use it to create answers for SO.

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing information about why this change made it work.